# Geting context of recylerview item instead of its postion android

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I have a recylerview in my app, I am able to get the postions of each item however, I am not quite sure how to get the context of the postion from recylerview;

```
    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "clicked" + " " + position, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            })
    );
```

Also, the structure each item/column contain one textView to which I am adding data like this;

```
list.add(new itemtoadd("John Smith" + "\nMale" + "\nSingle”));
```

What I want to do is because I only have one textview contain 3 set of data Name+gender+status, whilst getting the context of the position I would like to only get 1 piece of data from it, for example the name of the person.

EDIT:

right now the code I have written gets the position of the recylerview item for example it will say clicked 1, what I want to do is instead of saying clicked 1, I want it to get the context of position 1 for example, in this case get 'John Smith, Male, Single'

What I mean is, say for example I have this data in my recylerview;

```
list.add(new itemtoadd("John Smith0" + "\nMale0" + "\nSingle0”));
list.add(new itemtoadd("John Smith1" + "\nMale1" + "\nSingle1”));
list.add(new itemtoadd("John Smith1" + "\nMale1" + "\nSingle1”));
```

in this case, the first data I add to my recylerview would be in position 0, instead of printing out 'position 0' I want to get the data in poition 0, which in this case would be; John Smith0, Male0, Single0.

Comment: What do you mean by "context of the position"? Where do you need it?

Comment: what are your exact needs? what do you mean by context at position?

Comment: see edited please, if it still doesn't make sense let me know and I will try explaining it better

Comment: Your edit does not explain what "context of the position" means. Do you mean the model object from your `RecyclerView.Adapter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your model object `itemtoadd` to retrieve your data, not the `TextView`:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

    Snackbar.make(view, "clicked" + " " + position, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();

    itemtoadd yourItem = list.get(position); // here you get your clicked model item

    // then you can get the String value from your "itemtoadd" model.
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here's an example how your `itemtoadd` model can be:

```
public class itemtoadd {

    private String mName;
    private String mGender;
    private String mStatus;


    public itemtoadd(String name, String gender, String status){
       mName = name;
       mGender = gender;
       mStatus = status;
    }

    public String getName(){
      return mName;
    }

    public String getGender(){
      return mGender;
    }

    public String getStatus(){
      return mStatus;
    }

    public String getPersonInformation(){
      return getName()+"\n"+getGender()+ "\n"+getStatus();
    }

}
```

With the class above you can get your the *name*, *gender*, *status* with respectively `yourItem.getName()`, `yourItem.getGender()`, `yourItem.getStatus()`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, what is itemtoadd referring to?

Comment: because when I write itemtoadd it says unable to resolve symbol itemtoadd

Comment: In your OP, there is `list.add(new itemtoadd("John Smith" + "\nMale" + "\nSingle”)` , so i'am assuming that you have Model object named *"itemtoadd"*, don't you?

Comment: works now, is this data now store in yourItem variable? if I want to print this data on a snackbar how can I do that?

Comment: Yes, it's in *yourItem* variable... It depends on how your *itemtoadd.class* looks like. Post its code, maybe you have a getter method that return the String value.

Comment: Say for example, like shown in my edit above, I have 3 peices of data added in my recylerview. How can I print the position 0, position 1, position 2 data? Currently, I have this; yourItem.getPersonInformation(); where should I specify the position to get?

Comment: You can't print value by positions, because *yourItem.getPersonInformation();* will return (for the second item) *'John Smith1 Male1 Single1'* as String, because its considered like a signle data. If you want to separate the data, you need to change your model class *itemtoadd* to have 3 String variable (one for each information)